# Change Button color and shape properties

Tags: xml, android-studio, button, layout

Here is my button appearance :
[image: button]

Which is actually defined by :

```
        <Button
            style="@style/Button.Pressed"
            android:id="@+id/standardRestock"
            android:layout_width="165dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/button_checked_style"
            android:fontFamily="@font/pragatinarrow"
            android:text="@string/standard"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
```

My style is defined by :

```
    <style name="Button.Pressed" parent="android:Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/dp_button_checked</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    </style>
```

My background is currently defined by :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/grey_button_checked" />

    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/grey_button_checked" />

    <item android:drawable="@color/grey_button">
        <shape>
            <stroke
                android:width="5dp"
                android:color="@color/redcheckborder" />
            <corners
                android:radius="4dp"/>
        </shape>

    </item>

</selector>
```

In short, my button should be grey and red, but AS decide to keep the default colorPrimary.
Uh, and i tried to change android:background to backgroundTint, keep the same.

What did I miss ?

PS : "@color/button_checked_style" looks like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/grey_button" android:state_checked="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/redcheckborder" android:state_checked="true" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the line android:state_checked="false" from "false" to "true"

Answer (score 0):

Found...Use AppCompat Button, the current one isn't modify allowed.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
```

instead of

```
<Button
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/grey_button_checked"/>
            <corners
            android:radius="5dp"/>
            <stroke
            android:color="@color/redcheckborder"
            android:width="4dp">
            </stroke>

        </shape>
    </item>



    <item
        android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/grey_button"/>
            <corners
                android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

in the XML drawable file